# Is it possible to have (an undefined number of) optional segments in the Ember router?

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I would like to collect extra segments from the Ember router in an array.
Here is a made-up `path` to illustrate what I mean:

```
this.route('group', {path: 'group/:group_id(/:segments[])*'}, function() {
```

Is it possible to use a request like this:

```
GET /group/123/some/path/segments
```

And have them collected in an array?

```
group.id = 123
segments = ['some', 'path', 'segments']
```

Or is there any way to define optional segments, so I can just add many and collect them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, the router is using [route-recognizer](https://github.com/tildeio/route-recognizer) to determine the routes. There is the notion of `star-segments`

```
router.add([{ path: "/pages/*path", handler: page }]);

result = router.recognize("/pages/hello/world");
result === [{ handler: page, params: { path: "hello/world" } }];
```

This seems like what you're looking for

As a side note, this is my usual 404 approach:

```
Router.map(function() {
  ...very last route
  this.route('not-found', { path: "/*path"});
});
```

routes/not-found.js:

```
export default Route.extend({
    model(params){
        return params.path
    }
});
```

not-found.hbs

```
404: /{{model}} not found!
```

such that `/foo/bar` yields: `404: /foo/bar not found!`

Comment: This is (almost) exactly what I'm looking for. I just need to `params.path.split('/')` and I'm set. Thank you.